# Jetson TK1 - Embedded Linux - How to Periodic Interrupt

Tags: c++, embedded, embedded-linux, interrupt, nvidia

[The official webpage for the Jetson TK1](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/downloads) is quite complicated for the new user and I can't find a document/webpage/book/course to start studying the Jetson TK1's API focusing on GPIO pins, interrupts etc.

My Questions:

1) After hours of search, I guess I should study Embedded Linux. There are many options, and most of the "practical" books are about BeagleBone Black. Are there any books/courses focusing directly on practical Jetson TK1 applications; Or do you suggest another approach?

2) Can you show a very short code snippet on periodic interrupts & interrupt handling for the Jetson TK1? (in C++ preferably). Does not have to be a complete and fully working code.

Side Note: Currently using board as if it is a Ubuntu installed desktop computer, but I'm not able to interact with sensors, LEDs yet. My knowledge about this platform is lacking, but I had studied TI's TM4C previously.

Answer (score 1):

Have you dug through the content here:  [Elinux.org Jetson_TK1 pages](http://elinux.org/Jetson_TK1) There's a link on that page to an ebook as well.  As for GPIOs this page http://elinux.org/Jetson/GPIO contains links to Tutorials.